# Is "You are correct" correct?

Tags: word-usage

It seems to me that "You are correct" means that the person in question is supposedly "correct" in their quiddity. "That is correct" or "You are right" seems a lot better.

I also would like to know if someone is using correct(ly) correctly, as to correct someone who is potentially using correctly incorrectly.

Comment: Is there any reason why you feel a lot better using the 2 examples?

Comment: I have always thought about "You are correct" to be an elided form of "You are correct [in your assumption] or [in your thinking]" etc

Comment: I always thought it impolite to comment on someone's quiddity.

Answer (score 7):

In English the verb "to be" ("you are") does not only refer to matters of quiddity ('essence'). We say "you are here" or "you are cold" all of which refer to transient properties of 'you'. If you are perhaps translating from Spanish, the English "to be" is used for both "ser" and "estar".

As such one is perfectly correct to say "You are correct". Generally the sense in which you are correct ought to be obvious - for example, the statement you just made. It would not be normal to say "you are correct" with no context implying what it is that is correct about them.

EXCEPTION: As well as 'right', 'correct' can also mean "in accordance with an acknowledged or accepted standard". With that meaning you could say "you are correct" without an implied context.

Comment: Re that last *without an implied context* point, it seems to me we almost always need *something* besides the bare unqualified statement. So "contextless" *John is correct* doesn't really work, but we can certainly say *John is **very** correct* to signify that John normally acts and speaks in accordance with accepted standards (usually, but not always, with the implication that he's *excessively* "correct").

Comment: Why would "John is very correct" be acceptable but "John is correct" be unacceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure "unacceptable" is the right way to describe it. But surely you agree that *in practice* you probably wouldn't respond *John is correct* even to a contextualising question such as *What's John like?* And you'd be *extremely* unlikely to simply come out with it as a "conversation starter" or statement "apropos nothing".